# how to get same values if an array have values same with values of anther array values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, search

Having two arrays of `authRoom` and `partiRoom` with one same value inside them. Want to find that same value if it was matched

Found `array_search` function that work only with single variable

```
$authRoom = [8, 7, 1, 22, 13, 18, 10];
```

```
$partiRoom= [3, 6, 5, 9, 8];
```

I want the output to be `8` which is the same value of these two arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_intersect` which will give you an array of the same values in both `$authRoom` and `$partiRoom` like so:

```
$authRoom = [8, 7, 1, 22, 13, 18, 10];
$partiRoom = [3, 6, 5, 9, 8];

$res = array_intersect($authRoom, $partiRoom);
print_r($res); // [8]
```

If you want to get the value `8` outside of the array, you can simply access the first value using index `0`:

```
$res = array_intersect($authRoom, $partiRoom)[0];
echo $res; // 8
```